# Error Bottom Navigation con Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

quiero abrir un fragment al seleccionar un Item del Bottom Navigation que creé, pero el código siguiente es el que no me deja continuar por que aparece erroneo en el **fragment antes del fragment.getTag** y no se como solucionarlo. GRACIAS

> (R.id.contentLayout, fragment, fragment.getTag()).commit();

aquí mi código completo :

*MainActivity.java*

```
bottomNavigationView =(BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navegation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            if (item.getItemId()== R.id.consultaItem){

                citaFragment fragment = new citaFragment();
                android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentLayout,
                        //aquí tengo el error -> fragment,
                        fragment.getTag()).commit();

            }


            else if (item.getItemId()== R.id.inicioItem) {


               mensajeRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                        infoTextView.setText(value);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                return true;


            }
            else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.ubicacionItem) {

                //infoTextView.setText(R.string.precio);
                return true;


            }


            return false;
        }
    });
```

*fragment_cita*

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.a60393.example.citaFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/citaTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Cita:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="35dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horaFechaTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/_12_mayo_2017"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="424242"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas instanciando un

> android.app.FragmentManager

Por lo que este espera el mismo tipo en lugar de tu fragment que es

> android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Reemplaza de la siguiente forma:

```
Fragment fragment = new citaFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentLayout,
        fragment,
        fragment.getTag()).commit();
```

Comment: Hola, lo acabo de probar y no funcionó :(

Comment: Edito la respuesta, prueba de la siguiente manera

Comment: @Israel si intentas explicar tu respuesta en lugar de solo poner código seria mas sencillo para el OP adaptar tu respuesta a su problema.

Comment: Ok ahora lo pruebo

Comment: Listp, no me dió error, deja checo si funciona!

Comment: SI BRO!! GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas agregar la descripción del `Fragment`, únicamente el contenedor y la instancia del `Fragment`:

```
citaFragment fragment = new citaFragment();
 android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
 //manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment, fragment.getTag()).commit();
 manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Hola bro, ya lo pude solucionar, no se si con la respuesta que me diste funcione, es más lo probaré y te aviso ;)

Comment: No :( así no funcionó, pero muchas gracias!!! Igual :)

Comment: Te sugiero agregues tu respuesta.