# Ir desde un activity a un fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

EStoy creando una aplicacion en la que el usuario parte desde un fragment, se le redirecciona a un activity donde introduce una serie de datos y quiero que vuelva al fragment desde el que salió. Pero a la hora de volver al fragment de partida el intent me da error.

Si pongo:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddClothingSetActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

La aplicación carga el fragment de inicio, pero yo no quiero que cargue este.

He probado con:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddClothingSetActivity.this, ClothingSetsFragment.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Que es el fragment al que quiero ir, pero me da error. Error: Unable to find explicit activity class. Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? La actividad del que cuelga el fragment esta declarada, ¿Cómo ir al fragment que deseo?

Aqui el codigo del layout del activity AddClothingSetActivity:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/textViewWhite"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/textViewClothes"
    android:layout_below="@id/textViewWhite"
    android:text="Prendas"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewClothes"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewClothes">
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/scrollViewClothes"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAdd">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddClothes"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Añadir prendas"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextClothingSetsName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutAdd"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextClothingSetsDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Descripcion"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_below="@id/editTextClothingSetsName"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/editTextClothingSetsDescription">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/FABEditClothingSets"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:borderWidth="16dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Amigo CMorillo me parece que esta mal entendiendo el uso de los Fragments, el Fragment se agrega dentro de una Activity , usar un Intent no es posible, te sugiero agregar el layout de AddClothingSetActivity para tener más información. http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/fragments-en-android/

Comment: Gracias por el enlace, he editado la pregunta con el codigo del layout

Comment: Los fragment a los que me refiero son del tipo Navigation Drawer

Comment: puede que me este confundiendo pero, supongo haces algo en el activity que abres, y al terminar no le puedes hacer un finish() ?, asi terminas el activity que abriste, y te dejaria en el activity anterior que contiene el ultimo fragment que desplegaste (que es el que mando a llamar al activity)

Comment: Que activities tienes y que fragments? Si estas usando un Nav Drawer, éste tiene una sola activity y varios fragments

Comment: @armen el activity de los fragment es MainActivity. Los fragment son Clothesfragment (el cual es el principal) y luego dos mas, ClothingSetsFragment(al cual quiero ir) y CalendarFragment

Comment: entonces tu pregunta esta mal. Debe ser de fragment a fragment. Y pasa eso se usa Fragment Transaction. Mira las respuestas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70160/error-bottom-navigation-con-fragment. Los intent son para ir entre Activities

Comment: @CMorillo agregué un ejemplo de como realizar la transacción, esto lo puedes realizar desde tu Activity AddClothingSetActivity dentro de onCreate().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No se puede abrir un `Fragment` usando un `Intent`.**

Lo que se realiza es realizar transacciones de `Fragments` dentro de un `FrameLayout`, si tu tienes especificado un `FrameLayout`, es aquí donde puedes cargar tus Fragments:

Para agregar el `Fragment` llamado `ClothingsSetsFragment` simplemente realiza una transacción para agregar el `Fragment` :

```
        //Obtiene el Fragment manager
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        //agrega el Fragment en el contenedor, en este caso el FrameLayout con id `FrameLayout`.
        ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new ClothingsSetsFragment());
        ft.commit();
```