# have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

tengo un problema con solo una lista, lo que pasa es que quiero que me salgan 10 elementos, pero solo me aparece uno. Pienso que es por mi activity y fragment, pero ¿qué código tendría que ponerle?. Aparte, me sale un error en el "logcat" que dice "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Logcat

```
08-30 22:31:23.981 2603-2664/? W/AASAInstall:  updated apk:com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer   uid:-1
08-30 22:31:28.391 2603-2664/? W/PackageManager: Code path for pkg : com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer changing from /data/app/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer-2 to /data/app/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer-1
08-30 22:31:28.391 2603-2664/? W/PackageManager: Resource path for pkg : com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer changing from /data/app/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer-2 to /data/app/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer-1
08-30 22:31:30.076 2603-2603/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer'!
08-30 22:31:30.881 2603-2603/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer'!
08-30 22:31:30.946 4206-4206/? E/SPPClientService: [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] PackageName : com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer, true, false
    [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] Ignore Replacing case
08-30 22:31:31.426 2603-2603/? W/BackupManagerService: Removing schedule queue dupe of com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer
08-30 22:31:32.036 3057-3057/? E/Launcher.Model: onPackageChanged :com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer
08-30 22:31:32.746 4293-4293/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer, PID: 4293
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.FragmentActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1837)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1534)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4125)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4072)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4396)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4364)
        at com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
08-30 22:31:32.851 2603-3486/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/.FragmentActivity
08-30 22:31:33.661 2603-2652/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{1fa90a00 u0 com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/.FragmentActivity t12 f}
08-30 22:31:34.691 2847-2847/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:31:38.316 4275-4275/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:33:00.406 4941-4941/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:33:28.741 5447-5447/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer, PID: 5447
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.FragmentActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1837)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1534)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4125)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4072)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4396)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4364)
        at com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
08-30 22:33:28.746 2603-3091/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/.FragmentActivity
08-30 22:33:29.276 2603-2652/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2c42a0c9 u0 com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/.FragmentActivity t13 f}
08-30 22:33:30.301 2847-2847/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:35:54.861 5726-5726/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:41:05.371 6355-6355/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:59:26.871 11998-11998/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 23:03:33.836 13685-13685/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
```

*Aquí esta mi código de Activity

[image]

*"AndroidManifest.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



    <activity android:name=".My_fragment_activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

*activity_note_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:id="@+id/cardview">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto"
            android:text="Hola texto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:text="Hola titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:text="Hola body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/xd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/yopyop" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

*NotesAdapter.java

```
package com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.POJOS.Note;
import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.R;

import java.util.List;

public class NotesAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.ViewHolder>{ 

Context context;
List<Note> noteList;

public NotesAdapter(Context context, List<Note> noteList){
    this.context = context;
    this.noteList = noteList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_note_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Todo_esto se aplica al TextView, y es obvio de que el TextView SOLO recibe texto(cadenas);
    holder.texto.setText(String.valueOf(noteList.get(position).getId()));
    holder.tituto.setText(String.valueOf(noteList.get(position).getTitle()));
    holder.body.setText(String.valueOf(noteList.get(position).getBody()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return noteList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{ 

    CardView cardView;
    TextView texto, tituto, body;
    ImageView imageView;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        texto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texto);
        tituto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        body = itemView.findViewById(R.id.body);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.xd);
    }
}

}
```

*RecycleViewFragment.java

```
package com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.Adapters.NotesAdapter;
import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.POJOS.Note;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class RecycleViewFragment extends Fragment{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Note> lista;
private NotesAdapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    //Método donde se inicializa los datos
    initializedData();
    adapter = new NotesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), lista);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void initializedData(){
    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(new Note(1,"Nota 1", "Este es el teto de la nota 1"));
    lista.add(new Note(2,"Nota 2", "Este es el teto de la nota 2"));
    lista.add(new Note(3,"Nota 3", "Este es el teto de la nota 3"));
    lista.add(new Note(4,"Nota 4", "Este es el teto de la nota 4"));
    lista.add(new Note(5,"Nota 5", "Este es el teto de la nota 5"));
    lista.add(new Note(6,"Nota 6", "Este es el teto de la nota 6"));
    lista.add(new Note(7,"Nota 7", "Este es el teto de la nota 7"));
    lista.add(new Note(8,"Nota 8", "Este es el teto de la nota 8"));
    lista.add(new Note(9,"Nota 9", "Este es el teto de la nota 9"));
    lista.add(new Note(10,"Nota 10", "Este es el teto de la nota 10"));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

*fragment_recyclerview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Creo que tu adapter viene incompleto, no veo la cardview

Comment: cierto, perdón por el inconveniente, ya esta!!!

Comment: En tu `FragmentActivity` estas inicilizando el layout `setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_item);` que solo contiene el diseño
con el que funcionara tu adaptador.

Comment: ¿y qué código debería ponerle amigo? esa es exactamente mi duda

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal puedes crear un contenedor en una actividad e inicializar tu fragmento `RecycleViewFragment.java` para ver los resultados.

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero ahora me sale "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?" y no sé que código aplicar.

Comment: El problema esta en tu fragment activity observa que le estas asignando este layout (activity_note_item) este solo es el modelo de cada row que llenara tu adaptador según los datos de la lista que recibe. Entonces, en la captura que mandaste estas viendo solo eso, la plantilla correcto? El problema es que el fragment no se esta mostrando y la razón es porque los fragments no se inician como si fuese una actividad, pon atención a tu código y nota que lo intentas mostrar con un **Intent** de acuerdo a la documentación de Google esta es la forma correcta de mostrar los fragmentos: https://develop

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje original es :

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Si o traducimos indica:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: no se puede encontrar la
>   clase de actividad explícita {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer /
>   com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment}; ¿Has declarado
>   esta actividad en tu AndroidManifest.xml?

Lo que sucede es que estas tratando de abrir el Fragment `RecycleViewFragment` mediante `startActivity()` y es incorrecto,

Primeramente solo se puede usar `startActivity()` para abrir Actividades pero estas deben extender de las clases AppCompatActivity, Activity etc, pero en este caso extiende de `Fragment`:

```
public class RecycleViewFragment extends Fragment{
```

y es importante que todas las Actividades deben ser declaradas en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, ejemplo:

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.myActivity"/>
```

En realidad **no se puede abrir un Fragment usando un Intent**, revisa esta respuesta que te proporciona un ejemplo depara que sepas como abrir un Fragment

[Ir desde un activity a un fragment](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153292/ir-desde-un-activity-a-un-fragment)

```
   //Obtiene el Fragment manager
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    //agrega el Fragment en el contenedor, en este caso el FrameLayout con id `FrameLayout`.
    ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new RecycleViewFragment());
    ft.commit();
```