# Error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class con AppCompatActivity dentro NavigationView

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, navigationview

No consigo entender que esta pasando. Soy nuevo en esto.

Este es **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    (...)

    public void Openwindow(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Esta es **myActivity.java**:

```
public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_window);
    }

}
```

Pero al pulsar el botón se cierra con error:

```
(...)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.app.myApp/com.app.myApp.ui.myWindows.myActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
(...)
```

Este es mi layout. Tomar en cuenta que el botón esta dentro un menu.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/menu_contact"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_menu_profile"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_profile"
            android:onClick="Openwindow" />

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Por ultimo, **fragment_window.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorSecondary"
    tools:context=".ui.myWindows.myActivity">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Estoy dando vueltas como un loco. Los demás botones me funcionan, pero cuando esta dentro un NavigationView no funciona. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Me faltó algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como lo dice tu error `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` debes declarar tu `myActivity.java` en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
<activity>
...
</activity>
<activity android:name=".myActivity"></activity>
```

Luego de eso tambien me gustaria mencionarte que no puedes abrir un fragment desde un intent, mira esta pregunta que tal vez te aclare algunas dudas respecto a tu error:

[Ir desde un activity a un fragment](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153292/ir-desde-un-activity-a-un-fragment)

Comment: Gracias. Se me paso por alto esa parte. -- No es un fragment, aunque hay un archivo que se llame asi, lo voy a renombrar.

Comment: Me alegro que haya sido de ayuda. Saludos!